# How do I add my new DNN module to my DNN website

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dotnetnuke

I've created my new DNN website and having added my DNN template I've added my new Module, I've tried adding my new module in DNN but cannot get it to load from the module list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know what you are doing wrong, we'll need to know what you have tried doing.

If you are using my module development templates (http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com) then you simply need to BUILD the module in RELEASE mode, then upload the INSTALL package from the Host/Extension page.

If you aren't using my templates, you will need to likely do one of the following.

1) Register the module manually via the Host/Extensions page
or
2) Register the module by using the "create module" option from Host/Extensions and looking for the .DNN file for your module.